# Android : set bitmap in new pdf

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I want to add few bitmaps in a new PDF.

I tried this :

```
    Document doc = new Document();
    Page page = doc.getPages().add();
    page.getParagraphs().add(img);
    doc.save(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/doc.pdf");
```

But I've few error, Document isn't found, so I tried to import what Android proposed to me, but nothings work. How is it work ? How can I do to add few bitmap in my pdf ?

Thx,